# Some Git commands are not showing result

Tags: git

Some git commands are not showing result. Actually they show nothing! For example `git config --list` has no output(I have set the config and can use git, but this command doesn't work). Or `git branch` doesn't show any branches (although there are 4 branches!). I can use this command to make branches; but when I want to see my branches it shows nothing!

I searched and couldn't find anything related.

edit:
I run commands in linux terminal with git version 2.25.1 and the commands doesn't working even in repo folder.

Comment: Where are you trying this? What terminal? Git version? Also, have you double-checked you're launching commands from a path inside your repo?

Comment: I'm sure the problem is in the pager. Try `git --no-pager`, for example `git --no-pager config --list`

Comment: I agree with Romain Valeri's implication: it sounds like you're having a problem with the _tools_, but you have not told us what tools you're using. And in any case, knowing how to use tools is _not programming_ so one might argue that the question isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow (though one might also argue the opposite, of course).

Comment: @RomainValeri Sorry for lack of information. I'm runnig commands in linux terminal with git version 2.25.1. And yeah I run commands in a repo path.

Comment: @phd Thanks! But why they don't work without ```--no-pager```?

Comment: @ErfanMojibi As I've said it's a problem with the pager but you didn't say what pager you do use and how it's configured. Is it `less`? Is there environment variable `$LESS`? Please show us the text output of `git var GIT_PAGER` and `echo $LESS`

Comment: On my system the pager is set to a chain of symlinks, so to print the pager program, I used `readlink -f $(which $(git var GIT_PAGER))`, printing `/usr/bin/less` on my system. Maybe a symlink is broken on @ErfanMojibi's system.